# I have some error with checkbox inside my angular template driven form,,

Tags: angular, forms, angular-template-form

I have a template driven form include the checkboxes like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Communication</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">       
            <input type="checkbox" name="email" #email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="projectSettings.communication.email" value="email">Email
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="sms" #sms="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="projectSettings.communication.sms" value="sms">SMS
        </label>

        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" name="phone" #phone="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="projectSettings.communication.phone" value="phone">Phone
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have two dataModel first like:

```
import { Communication } from './communication.model';

export class WizardData {
    id: number;
    name: string = '';
    owner: string = '';
    customer: string = '';
    email: string = '';
    phone: string = '';
    webSite: string = '';
    language: string = '';
    time: string = '';
    communication: Communication; 
    address1: string = '';
    address2: string = '';
    postCode: string = '';
    state: string = '';
    country: string = '';
    city: string = '';

    clear() {
        this.name = '';
        this.owner = '';
        this.customer = '';
        this.email = '';
        this.phone = '';
        this.webSite = '';
        this.language = '';
        this.time = '';
        this.communication.email = '';
        this.communication.sms = '';
        this.communication.phone = '';
        this.address1= '';
        this.address2= '';
        this.postCode= '';
        this.city = '';
        this.state= '';
        this.country = '';
    }
}


export class ProjectDetails {
    name: string = '';
    owner: string = '';
    customer: string = '';
    email: string = '';
    phone: string = '';
    webSite: string = '';
}


export class ProjectSettings {
    language: string = '';
    time: string = '';
    communication: Communication;
}


export class DeliveryDetails {
    address1: string = '';
    address2: string = '';
    postCode: string = '';
    city: string = '';
    state: string = '';
    country: string = '';
}
```

and the other dataModel that is inside last one is like:

```
export class Communication {
    email: Boolean = false;
    sms: Boolean = false;
    phone: Boolean = false;
}
```

when I run my app, have this error for inputs type="checkbox" on [(ngModel)]="projectSettings.communication.email" part(as I delete it and everything would be OK!):

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ProjectSettingsComponent.html:26)

pls help!

Comment: can you please provide working demo on stackblitz ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are obtaining the data through some async method, which means that the `projectSettings.communication` is not set yet. You should either use a resolver, to get your data before your component renders, or use an `*ngIf` so you can wait for it:

```
<div *ngIf="projectSettings.communication" class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Communication</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">       
      <input type="checkbox" name="email" #email="ngModel"
             [(ngModel)]="projectSettings.communication.email" value="email">
        Email
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="sms" #sms="ngModel" 
             [(ngModel)]="projectSettings.communication.sms" value="sms">SMS
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="phone" #phone="ngModel" 
             [(ngModel)]="projectSettings.communication.phone" value="phone">Phone
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

If this doesn't show up the form, you should check your data response to see if the data structure is the same as your model structure